# NetBeans Plugin for flowchart

Tags: netbeans, plugins, flowchart

I am using netbeans 6.5. Is there any plugin available creating flowchart from the netbeans project? I am using jdk 1.6. I need to create simple flow chart of each and every method in the project.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no known plugin available ... but you can try 
the java based drawing tool [yed](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html)
there is a free version available which helps you to draw flowchart, BPEL, class diagrams and more.